# what endpoints should return a user;s access token in an authentication system using REST/GraphQL

Tags: api, rest, authentication, jwt

In a JWT authentication system is the login/signin endpoint the only endpoint that should return an access token?

I thought an access token can be returned for signup/register endpoint after confirmation of the user email/phone number

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unexpired access token, you are logged in and you can use the JWT to access the system.  I'd normally expect this to only be returned from a login endpoint or GraphQL mutation.  If you have another workflow that would cause a user to be "logged in" then it makes sense to return a JWT from this path as well; it would make sense to issue a token when the user enters their password the very first time rather than making them retype it.